# Regex for 1 or more integers followed by non integers

Tags: javascript, regex

[EDITED. *Altered "...integers is NOT followed..." in title. Text similarly altered.*]

I am looking for a JavaScript regex that matches strings where 1 or more integers is followed by non-integers.

So far I've got this...
    ([0-9][a-zA-Z])

...Which matches strings where integers are followed by letters, but this is not quite right.

Comment: Do you mean "1 or more integers followed by non-integers" (without the "NOT")? Otherwise, can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: Yes, sorry. This was poorly worded. What I wanted was "a regex to match all strings where integers are followed by non-integers"

Comment: I have edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you actually want "1 or more integers followed by a non-integer", this should work:

```
[0-9]+[^0-9]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `[0-9]+[^0-9]+` or `^[0-9]+[^0-9]+` if you want the numbers to be at the start of the string

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regular expression `\d+\D` to match one-or-more digit characters followed by a non-digit character.

```js
regexp = /\d+\D/;

tests = [
  "1",
  "1a",
  "1 ",
  "123!"
];

results = tests.map( function(str){
  return str + ": " + (regexp.test(str)?"matches":"does not match")
} );

alert( results.join( "\n" ) );
```